# How to use a key/value object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gun

I'm struggling to make use of an object in react, I'm trying to access the key:value that is being returned (and I can successfully console.log).

All the examples I've tried result in either mapping each character or throwing an object child error and i'm at a loss.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.gun.on('auth', () => this.thing());
  }

  thing() {
    this.gun.get('todos').map((value, key) => { console.log(key, value) }
    );
  }

  handleChange = e => this.setState({ newTodo: e.target.value })

  add = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.gun.get('todos').set(this.state.newTodo)
    this.setState({ newTodo: '' })
  }

  del = key => this.gun.get(key).put(null)

  render() {
    return <>
      <Container>
        <div>Gun</div>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.add}>
            <input value={this.state.newTodo} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <button>Add</button>
          </form>
          <br />
          <ul>
            {this.state.todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.key} onClick={_ => this.del(todo.key)}>{todo.val}</li>)}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Container></>
  }
}
```

Comment: Has the `gun` object been initialised correctly?

Comment: Yes, the code example is a working state of me console.logging the data i'm trying to map in react

Comment: Ok, to clarify - you're wanting your react component to update to show the changes that you make to the `gun` object?

Comment: ideally, but my focus at this stage is using that data at all. If I try to map it directly, it errors because its an object, if i map to an array i cant seem to keep the key.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to synchronize your components state with another data source (ie the `gun` object) - one simple approach would be to cache a copy of the `todo` data that you plan to render, in your component's `state`.

This is done via the `setState()` function which when called, causes the component to re-render. In the case of your component's `render()` method, changing the `todos` state field will updated list to display.

With this approach, you'd need to ensure that when you make changes to the `gun` object's todos data, you also update the components `todo` state via `setState()` as shown below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    /* Setup inital state shape for component */
    this.state = {
        todos : [], 
        newTodo : ''
    }
}

mapTodos() {
    return this.gun.get('todos').map((value, key) => ({ key : key, val : value }));
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.gun.on('auth', () => this.mapTodos());
}

handleChange = e => this.setState({ newTodo: e.target.value })

add = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.gun.get('todos').set(this.state.newTodo)

    /* When adding a todo, update the todos list of the component's internal state
    to cause a re-render. This also acts as a cache in this case to potentially speed
    up render() by avoiding calls to the gun.get() method */
    this.setState({ newTodo: '', todos : this.mapTodos() })
}

del = key => {
    this.gun.get(key).put(null)

    /* Call setState again to update the todos field of the component state to
    keep it in sync with the contents of the gun object */
    this.setState({ newTodo: '', todos : this.mapTodos() })
}

render() {
    return <Container>
        <div>Gun</div>
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.add}>
            <input value={this.state.newTodo} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <button>Add</button>
            </form>
            <br />
            <ul>
            {this.state.todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.key} onClick={ () => this.del(todo.key) }>{todo.val}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </Container>
}
```

Comment: mapTodo's isn't actually setting the data on this.state.todos, if I add that in it's undefined (I expect it to throw an object error but not sure why its undefined, the console log returns the correct data)

Comment: If I lose the () after `this.mapTodos` that resolves the undefined issue, but then we're back to the issue of it `.map` isn't a function on `this.state.todos` (presumably because its an object?)

Comment: @jhizzle207 my apologies, noticed I missed a `return` statement - just updated answer (see changes to `mapTodos()`). Does this help?

Comment: back to square one: 

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: @jhizzle207 made a small change to the `onClick` handler on your `<li>` - any progress with that?

Comment: No, the object issue remains.

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you replace `{todo.val}` with `{JSON.stringify(todo)}` ?

Comment: Still get the objects error, so the page doesn't load to see what the output is...

Comment: Would you be able to upload your project to GitHub for me to have a look at it in full?